# How to remove all data after last dot using php?

Tags: php, substr, strpos

How to remove all data after last dot using php ?

I test my code. It's echo just `aaa`

I want to show `aaa.bbb.ccc`

How can i do that ?

```
<?PHP
$test = "aaa.bbb.ccc.gif";
$test = substr($test, 0, strpos($test, "."));
echo $test;
?>
```

Comment: You need `strrpos` instead of `strpos`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this also -

```
$test = "aaa.bbb.ccc.gif";

$temp = explode('.', $test);

unset($temp[count($temp) - 1]);

echo implode('.', $temp);
```

**O/P**

```
aaa.bbb.ccc
```

> strpos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

You need to use `strrpos`

> strrpos — Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string

```
$test = "aaa.bbb.ccc.gif";
$test = substr($test, 0, strrpos($test, "."));
echo $test;
```

**O/P**

```
aaa.bbb.ccc
```

Answer (score 13):

You can utilize the function of `pathinfo()` to get everything before the dot

```
$str = "aaa.bbb.ccc.gif";
echo pathinfo($str, PATHINFO_FILENAME); // aaa.bbb.ccc
```

Comment: `pathinfo` would be best for files.

Comment: @Andrew, interesting solution!)

Comment: @Sougata true,  the reason I propose this solution is that I saw the string end with .gif and to me every string accepted function is just a way to manipulate a string :D

Comment: if the string is a url it will strip everything but the filename

Comment: This didn't quite format correctly for files with characters such as `「` or `」`